# How to send image from matlab to android over bluetooth?

Tags: android, matlab

### Problem:

I want to send an image from matlab to android over bluetooth.

Matlab and android are connected to each other and I can send strings without a problem.

```
fprintf(tabletObj, 'sleep');
```

I have a really huge byteArray containing the image I want to send to android. Here you can see just the first bytes:

```
planString = [-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,72,8,6,0,0,0,85,-19,-77,71,0,0,0,4,115,66,73,84,8,8,8,8,124,8,100,-120,0,0,29,2,73,68,65,84,120,-100,-75,-100,121,-68,37, ... ]
```

After that, I set in matlab the OutputBufferSize to the size of the image and send it to the tablet.

```
s = whos('planString');
obj1.OutputBufferSize = s.bytes;


% Send it to tablet
fwrite(tabletObj, planString, 'int8');
```

In android you can see following incoming bytes.

[image: incoming bytes in android]

Why are there just the first 6 bytes and not more?
The next incoming bytes are more then just 6 bytes, why?

[image: seccond part of incoming bytes in android]

I set the buffersize in android to the same size like matlab.

```
private void listen() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[picSize];  // buffer store for the stream
    Log.i(TAG, "buffer length" + buffer.length);

    while (true) {
    try {
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        newMessageReceived(new String(buffer, "UTF-8")); // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
    } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
    }
}
}
```

---

### **Edit #1:**

I used following code to get only the "right" bytes and put that into an ArrayList with bytes. Now, it seems like that I have just the needed bytes. But it's too slow! You need to wait for more than 1 min. to get all bytes from matlab. Is there a better solution? Why are the incoming bytes split sometimes in 3, sometimes in 15, ...? (see picture below code)

```
ArrayList<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

...

int nread = inputStream.read(buffer);
byte[] newOne = new byte[nread];
System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newOne, 0, nread);
bytes.add(newOne);
```

[image]

Comment: Is it always the 26 aka substitute character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) stopping the transmission?

Comment: 'inputStream.read(buffer);'. Change to 'int nread = inputStream.read(buffer);'. Then use nread in the following statement to construct a String with the right content/length.

Comment: But thats not all. You will get them in chunked and are not glueing them together.

Comment: @Daniel no it's not. This is what I send: [-119, 80, 78, 71, 26, 80, 78, 71, 13, 26, 71, 13, 26] and this is what I receive in android: [-119,80,78,71,26,80,78,71,13,26,71,13,26]

Comment: I tried it and edit my question @greenapps.

Comment: Do not make new bytes or an extra arraylist. Just declare one buffer wich can hold the whole message. Than read directly in the buffer like int nbytes = 0; And now the loop: int nread = inputtSream.read(buffer, nbytes, buffer.length-nbytes);  nbytes += nread;

Comment: `You need to wait for more than 1 min.`. Well if you do not tell the size of your image in bytes we can not say much.

Comment: @greenapps It has a size from 59.880 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void listen() {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[10000]; 
      int nbytes = 0;

      while (true) {
        try {
            int nread = inputStream.read(buffer, nbytes, buffer.length - nbytes);
            nbytes += nread;
            ... // after getting all bytes
            newMessageReceived(buffer, nbytes); // Send bytes to the UI activity
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
      } 
}
```

@greenapps thanks for the solution.